# Jenkin "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" getting error while installing plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, installation, jenkins-blueocean

We are trying to set up jenkins. When we trying to install plugin getting the below error. We also tried to import the trusted certificate into the JVM directly still getting same error.

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Can anyone please suggest me solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get round the certificate error by downloading the [skip-certificate-check](https://plugins.jenkins.io/skip-certificate-check/releases/) plugin to my laptop and manually installing it in the  `Deploy Plugin` section in the Jenkins UI (at `/manage/pluginManager/advanced`). This is just for a development instance though, for a production instance you're probably better following some of the [other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563694/jenkins-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-whil) for fixing certificate issues properly.